# Is it possible to open a new file that starts with '+'?

Tags: filesystem, escape

I cannot figure out how to open a file that starts with `+`, e.g. `+models/File.m`. This is a naming convention for packages in Matlab.

I've tried escaping `\+models/File.m`.  This doesn't work because the backslash is interpreted by the shell.  Double escaping `\\+models/File.m` allows vim to receive the backslash,  but it then opens `\+models/File.m` literally.

The only way to do this seems to be by creating the file first with `touch` or whatever, and then opening inside vim with Ctrl-P.  I don't want to `cd` into `+models` because I am also working on files in sibling directories.  Any Ideas?

Thanks

My shell is bash if that makes a difference.

Comment: On the command line: `vim -- +models/File.m`.  From Vim: `:e \+models/File.m`

Comment: @SatoKatsura Please add the command line part as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `vim --help:`

```
Arguments:
   --                   Only file names after this
...
```

So this works on the command line:

```
vim -- +models/File.m
```

From inside Vim you need to escape the `+`:

```
:e \+models/File.m
```

Comment: I was thrown off inside vim because tab-completion no longer works with the \.  I never thought to just try it. Doh.

Comment: @maxf130 Tab completion works if  you write the directory: `:e \+models/<Tab>`

Comment: Clearly my attention span is to low.  I never made it past the first few characters.

Comment: @maxf130 Note that using `--` to stop argument parsing is pretty standard for commandline tools. e.g. `rm -- -r`, `less -- -f`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, you can start by specifying a directory name, so that the + (plus sign) appears *in the middle* of the file specification instead of at the beginning.

Because all *nix operating systems, and others like MS-DOS / Windows that adopted Unix conventions, (just about any place you can run *vim*...,) refer to the current directory as `.` ("dot", "period", and so on,) then you can specify **any** file name beginning with an unusual symbol by preceding it with the string `./` (or in Windows with back- instead of forward-slash `.<`) and thus:

```
./+models/File.m
```

just about anywhere that you can use a "regular" file name.

Answer (score 2):

You can open `vim` without any arguments.
And then, in command line, type `:e! \+filename`

Comment: +1 This works, though it would be better if this were possible from the command line.